How can I correctly install Citrix Workplace on Kubuntu 2404
After installing Kubuntu 2404, I downloaded and installed Citrix Workspace app for Linux.
sudo dpkg -i ./icaclient_24.5.0.76_amd64.deb
I see it in the programs (via windows key --> type citrix) but it does not start.
I found a similar issue on:
Citrix Workplace not starting
In var/log/syslog I see the following error:
/opt/Citrix/ICAClient/selfservice: error while loading shared libraries: libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
The same error is reveiled after:
cd /opt/Citrix/ICAClient
./selfservice
This problem seems not uniquely linked to Citrix, more software is needs libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37
Suggestions to solve this issue:

link to new library with old library name:
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.1.so.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjavascriptcoregtk-4.1.so.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18

... Citrix just crashes

Install old library
sudo apt install libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37

.. its absent in the Ubuntu2404 repository

.. However this library is in /snap/gnome-42-2204/176/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

In Kubuntu 2404 there is a soft link to libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.67.8
(The softlink libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so refers to libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37, so it seems prudent to copy the 3 files)
(It's a soft link because the inodes differ, see: ls -i libwebkit*)
sudo cp libwebkit2gtk-4.0* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
After reinstalling, starting ICAClient results in a new error :
cd /opt/Citrix/ICAClient
./selfservice
./selfservice: error while loading shared libraries: libwpe-1.0.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Does one needs to track and all dependencies in such a way to get Citrix running? Or is there a simple solution to fix this?

Try adding snap library location to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/snap/gnome-42-2204/176/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

I'm sorry... but why is a general snap library relevant when installing Citrix using a downloaded .deb file? As far as I know, these software environments are not and should not be related to each other. Especially when the error is caused by new libraries, that don't play well with the .deb file

Just a coincidence that snap base might have the libraries Citrix needs. The proper solution is for Citrix to update their app to have 24.04 support

I had the same situation and i did something similar:

first i used the citrix workspacecheck util to identify missing dependencies and installed them: https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-workspace-app-for-linux/system-requirements.html#workspacecheck
then i ran citrix from the command line: /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/selfservice
it generates errors for missing libraries (e.g. libicudata.so.70) , which i found all of them in snap of other apps (Mainly OnlyOffice) e.g. sudo find / -name libicudata.so.70
i copied each of these libraries to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ e.g. sudo cp /snap/onlyoffice-ds/210/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.70 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
re-run citrix and re-copied them until citrix launched.

I'm afraid we will have to do this until citrix themselves prepare it for Ubuntu 24.
Best!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This is obviously a bit of a clunky solution, but I can confirm it got me out of a pinch this morning to get myself connected remotely - so thanks!
